# Terraform - how to create an AWS MediaConvert JobTemplate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-media-convert

I am new to Terraform and have begun creating `.tf` files for my infrastructure which so far involves AWS S3 and IAM Roles. All good so far.

But now I need to create an AWS MediaConvert JobTemplate via Terraform and I can't find any reference for this on the [Terraform's AWS provider documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html)?

I don't know what to do at this point? Can I even use Terraform to create MediaConvert resources or do I need to use another tool/means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't as of right now (2019-07-02). But you can vote for them to implement it here:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7533

Answer (score 0):

I made a mediaconvert job using aws lambda and boto3. The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/vidstream-inputVideoProcessor).

[image]
So aws lambda is triggered by s3 put notification and the python lambda creates a mediaconvert job. Everything is written using Terraform.

Hope this helps someone.